# Robot framework: Lists should be equal problem with empty values: "None" and ''

Tags: excel, list, robotframework, nonetype

So problem here is that I am comparing two lists from different locations. One list is from excel and other list is from particular table which represents the imported values of the same excel values.
So all values are correct; but the excel gives one or possbily more values which are "none" and from the table i get those values only empty value as astrophes ''. How can i change "None" to '' or vice versa?
In this particular case "None" and '' are in the 10th value slot in lists but over time it can change because different values are put to the excel.
So how can I remove or replace/modify these "nones" to '':s or vice versa?

Excel list: [1, 'X', 'Y', 200, 1999, 'Z', 'W', 4, 'V', None, 2, 1100]
Table list: [1, 'X', 'Y', 200, 1999, 'Z', 'W', 4, 'V', '', 2, 1100]

Using ExcelLibrary and ExcelRobot to get the mixture of keywords .. below is the similar approach

```
${iTotalRows} =   Get Row Count    Sheet1 (etc.) # excel

${item1} =      Get Table cell     //table[@class="xx"]    2        1
${item1} =      Get Table cell     //table[@class="xx"]    2        2 #etc..
Lists should be equal       ${x}       ${y}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a prepared keyword for this (e.g. in Collections library). If I'm wrong and I'm reinventing the wheel, please let me know, I can edit or delete my answer.

I'd create a custom keyword in Python and import it as a library into RF. This could be easily done in Python (one line in fact), so it doesn't even take much time or effort to create it.

**Libraries/ListUtils.py**:

```py
def substitute_values_in_list(list, value_to_substitute, substitute_to):
    return [substitute_to if ele == value_to_substitute else ele for ele in list]
```

Then in a test or in keywords:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ../Libraries/ListUtils.py    

*** Test Cases *** 
Empty List Value
    ${list}=    Create List    1    2    ${None}
    Log To Console    ${list}
    ${new_list}=    Substitute Values In List    ${list}    ${None}    ${Empty}
    Log To Console    ${new_list}
```

The first console output will be:

```
['1', '2', None]
```

and the second one with substituted values:

```
['1', '2', '']
```

You can parametrize custom keyword `Substitute Values In List` in another way, so you can substitute empty string for None values or something like that.